# How to stop apply() from changing order of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a reproducible example, toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_customers':['John','Foo'],'email':['email@gmail.com','othermail@yahoo.com'],'other_column':['yes','no']})

print(df)

  my_customers                email other_column
0         John      email@gmail.com          yes
1          Foo  othermail@yahoo.com           no
```

And I `apply()` a function to the rows, creating a new column inside the function:

```
def func(row):

    # if this column is 'yes'
    if row['other_column'] == 'yes':

        # create a new column with 'Hello' in it        
        row['new_column'] = 'Hello' 

        # return to df
        return row 

    # otherwise
    else: 

        # just return the row
        return row
```

I then apply the function to the df, and we can see that the order has been changed. The columns are now in alphabetical order. Is there any way to avoid this? I would like to keep it in the original order.

```
df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
print(df)

                 email my_customers new_column other_column
0      email@gmail.com         John      Hello          yes
1  othermail@yahoo.com          Foo        NaN           no
```

**Edited for clarification - the above code was too simple**

**input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_customers':['John','Foo'],
                   'email':['email@gmail.com','othermail@yahoo.com'],
                   'api_status':['data found','no data found'],
                   'api_response':['huge json','huge json']})

  my_customers                email     api_status api_response
0         John      email@gmail.com     data found    huge json
1          Foo  othermail@yahoo.com  no data found    huge json
```

Parsing the api_response. I need to create many new rows in the DF:

```
def api_parse(row):

    # if we have response data

    if row['api_response'] == huge json:

        # get response for parsing

        response_data = row['api_response']

        """Let's get associated URLS first"""

        # if there's a URL section in the response

        if 'urls' in response_data .keys():

            # get all associated URLS into a list

            urls = extract_values(response_data ['urls'], 'url')

            row['Associated_Urls'] = urls


        """Get a list of jobs"""

        if 'jobs' in response_data .keys():

            # get all associated jobs and organizations into a list

            titles = extract_values(person_data['jobs'], 'title')
            organizations = extract_values(person_data['jobs'], 'organization')

            counter = 1

            # create a new column for each job

            for pair in zip(titles,organizations):

                row['Job'+'_'+str(counter)] = f'Title: {pair[0]}, Organization: {pair[1]}'

                counter +=1


        """Get a list of education"""

        if 'educations' in response_data .keys():

            # get all degrees into list

            degrees = extract_values(response_data ['educations'], 'display')

            counter = 1

            # create a new column for each degree

            for edu in degrees:

                row['education'+'_'+str(counter)] = edu

                counter +=1


        """Get a list of social profiles from URLS we parsed earlier"""

        facebook = [i for i in urls if 'facebook' in i] or [np.nan]
        instagram = [i for i in urls if 'instagram' in i] or [np.nan]
        linkedin = [i for i in urls if 'linkedin' in i] or [np.nan]
        twitter = [i for i in urls if 'twitter' in i] or [np.nan]
        amazon = [i for i in urls if 'amazon' in i] or [np.nan]

        row['facebook'] = facebook
        row['instagram'] = instagram
        row['linkedin'] = linkedin
        row['twitter'] = twitter
        row['amazon'] = amazon

        return row 

    elif row['api_Status'] == 'No Data Found':
        # do nothing
        return row
```

**expected output:**

```
  my_customers                email     api_status api_response job_1 job_2  \
0         John      email@gmail.com     data found    huge json   xyz  xyz2   
1          Foo  othermail@yahoo.com  no data found    huge json   nan  nan

  education_1  facebook other api info  
0         foo  profile1            etc  
1         nan  nan                 nan
```

Comment: It is not a good design to add columns on the go while inside apply. Are you sure you need it this way? Looks like you could nail this with `np.where` or `np.select` pretty efficiently and, as an extra, also fix this column ordering problem

Comment: In my real world example I am parsing an API response that is saved in another column `df['api_response']`. I am reading the api response for each row, parsing the json and adding the extra data to the `df`. For example `row['geo_coordinates'] = api_data[geo]` etc etc. Is there a better way to do this? I am aware of `np.where` and `select` however i'm not sure if i could parse json with that and add it too the df.

Comment: there might be! Post your input and expected output, just a simple example to give an idea

Comment: Because of the size of my api response and the code it's difficult to post a reproducible example.  Anyway @rafaelc I realize the original question was way too simplified so i have edited my question to give you an idea of the type of function i need. can `np.where` work with a huge json response?

Comment: Try defining empty columns before calling `apply`: `df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns + ['facebook', 'instagram', 'linkedin', 'twitter', 'amazon', 'api_Status'])`

Comment: @SCool I understand a little better your problem now. Usually, for data manipulation like this, you'll prefer to manipulate everything in pure python rather than inside the `pandas` `apply` function. So, it's better to try to create either a (I) list of lists or (II) a dictionary to parse your data, and then, at the end of the process, call a `pd.DataFrame(build_data)` to have the final df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the order of columns in your `DataFrame` after running the apply function. For example:

```
df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
df = df[['my_customers', 'email', 'other_column', 'new_column']]
```

To reduce the amount of duplication (i.e. by having to retype all column names), you could get the existing set of columns before calling the apply function:

```
columns = list(df.columns)
df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
df = df[columns + ['new_column']]
```

---

Update based on the author's edits to the original question. Whilst I'm not sure if the data structure chosen (storing API results in a Data Frame) is the best option, one simple solution could be to extract the new columns after calling the apply functions.

```
# Store the existing columns before calling apply
existing_columns = list(df.columns)

df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)

all_columns = list(df.columns)
new_columns = [column for column in all_columns if column not in existing_columns]

df = df[columns + new_columns]
```

For performance optimisations, you could store the existing columns in a `set` instead of a `list` which will yield lookups in constant time due to the hashed nature of a set data structure in Python. This would change `existing_columns = list(df.columns)` to `existing_columns = set(df.columns)`.

---

Finally, as @Parfait very kindly points out in their comment, the code above may raise some depreciation warnings. Using [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) instead of `df = df[columns + new_columns]` will make the warnings disappear:

```
new_columns_order = [columns + new_columns]
df = df.reindex(columns=new_columns_order)
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea but my question is a simple example. In my current function I am adding up to 15 columns - different data from an API response.  Is it possible to do something like `df = df[columns + df.columns not in columns]` ? That way I can have the original order, plus the new columns added to the right of them.

Comment: Yes, if you have a list that consists of new columns, you could certainly do some filtering ahead. `existing_columns = list(df.columns)` would be the existing columns, and if you have a way to get `new_columns` as a list, then you could create list such as `columns_order = existing_columns + [x for column in new_columns if column not in existing_columns]`

Comment: @SCool I updated my answer based on the additional details that you provided.

Comment: Thanks so much @m_____z. This works and I've accepted it as the answer. Just on your comment that this might not be the best option for storing api results - is there a more efficient or recommended way to call the api, store and then parse big json responses for each row in a `df`?  No need to explain everything, just something i can google will do. Thanks again

Comment: That's hard to answer as I don't know the rest of your program and structure :) Normally when I do an API call via Python (e.g. the requests library) I store it in a dictionary or list of dictionaries and then change the data structure to something that's more appropriate to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Look into [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (i.e., my comment above) instead of bracketed column indexing as deprecated warnings may raise for latter. See [Indexing with list with missing labels is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated).

Comment: Thanks @Parfait! I updated my answer to point out `DataFrame.reindex`.

Comment: @SCool ... do not store data structures within a data structure (i.e., JSON inside a data frame). Keep a list/dict of JSONs outside a Pandas series/dataframe. In fact, even consider building data frame from this separate list then `merge` or `join` to main data frame instead of calling `apply`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice folks.

Answer (score 1):

That occurs because you don't assign a value to the new column if `row["other_column"] != 'yes'`. Just try this:

```
def func(row):

    if row['other_column'] == 'yes':

        row['new_column'] = 'Hello' 
        return row 

    else: 

        row['new_column'] = '' 
        return row

df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

You can choose the value for `row["new_column"] == 'no'` to be whatever. I just left it blank.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.